# jQuery select div with empty spans

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have div with 2 spans inside. I want to color this div on red only when both spans are empty. When minimum one span have value I want to color this specific parent div on for example blue. How to do this? Now I colorize all my divs, but I want to colorize only parent with empty spans. My code below

```js
$('#t').on('click', function(){
  var sum = 0;
  $('div span').each(function(){
     sum += parseFloat($(this).text().length);    
     if (sum != 0) {
        $(this).closest('section').find('.div').css("background", "blue");
     } else {
        $(this).closest('section').find('.div').css("background", "red");
     }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="div">  
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="div">  
          <span>b-1</span>
          <span>b-2</span>
        </div>        
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row"></div>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <input type="button" value="ss" id="t">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I know this is just a sample, but giving your divs a class of "div" is a bit confusing. The person answering has to wonder if the dot in the jQuery selector is missing on purpose or not. Side note: When a good answer comes along, please select one that comes with an explanation. These "code snippets as answers" are for the birds.

Comment: Good advice! I will remember that. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Basically the problem is that you are applying the same css prop to both divs because you are iterating the spans.

This way, iteraing the divs you encapsulate the result and the css property is applied individually.

```js
$('#t').on('click', function(){
  $('.div').each(function(){
    var sum = 0;
    $(this).children().each(function(){
        sum += parseFloat($(this).text().length);
    })
     if (sum != 0) {
        $(this).css("background", "blue");
     } else {
        $(this).css("background", "red");
     }
  });
});
```

```css
.div{
  min-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="div">  
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="div">  
          <span>b-1</span>
          <span>b-2</span>
        </div>        
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row"></div>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <input type="button" value="ss" id="t">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Where's the explanation?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a filter

```js
$('#t').on('click', function(e) {
  // just removed your other code for now

  e.preventDefault();

  $('.div').css('background', 'blue') // start all divs as blue
  .filter(function() {       
     return $(this).children('span:empty').length === 2;  // filter any divs with 2 empty spans
  }).css('background', 'red');  // make filtered results red
});
```

```css
.div {
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="div">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="div">
          <span>b-1</span>
          <span>b-2</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row"></div>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <input type="button" value="ss" id="t">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This is it! Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help :)  Hahaha and yet I get downvoted.  Some people on this site need to get a grip

Comment: I know I should make another thread but quick question. I want to display/hide other div instead of coloring. Lets say I have another div with class "hide". This div is under div with class "div". How Can I show "hide" when min one span is empty and hide it when span have value? I'm tying     $('.summary-error').css("display", "none");
    $('.btn-tt').on('click', function(e){
        $('.summary-mandatory').filter(function() {
            return $(this).children('span:empty').length === 2
        }).closest('.row').find('.summary-error').css('display', 'block');
    });

Comment: pretty much the same thing but toggle a class instead of the css background: https://jsfiddle.net/05oecovn/1/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/05oecovn/2/ it seems to working not what I want. See, I have div with message that div can't be empty. I want to show it when spans are empty and hide when spans are not empty.

Comment: hmm, it's display me message even if one span is not empty. This is what I want - two spans empty - show message, one span empty and one with value dont show message, two spans not empty dont show message. Can you help me with that?

Comment: I cahnged it to only need one span empty as you said in the above comment *How Can I show "hide" when min one span is empty*  if you have a look at the filter in the fiddle it is `>= 1` above is `==2`

Comment: ahh, my bad. I mislead you. I'm sorry. And Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery.text` - returns combined content of all selected elements. Then we can check the combined content of all child `span`s for each `div`.

```
$('#t').on('click', function(){
  var sum = 0;
  $('div').each(function(){
     if ($(this).find("span").length > 0) {
       if ($(this).find("span").text())
          $(this).css("background", "blue");
       else
          $(this).css("background", "red");
     }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close but you need to target the elements differently. I should also note that you have no height/width set on your empty div so the red one will not show up at this time.

However, here is your code working now:

https://jsfiddle.net/wecLLgmc/

```
$('#t').on('click', function(){
  $('.div').each(function(){
    var sum = 0;
     sum += parseFloat($(this).find('span').text().length);    
     console.log(sum)
     if (sum === 0) {
        $(this).css("background", "red");
     } else {
        $(this).css("background", "blue");
     }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of targeting the `spans` directly, you can loop over the `divs` with the specified class and check if this `div` contains at least an empty `span` using `$(this).find('span:empty').length`, change its color directly using `$(this).css()`.

This is how should be your code:

```
$('#t').on('click', function() {
  var sum = 0;
  $('div.myDiv').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('span:empty').length > 0) {
      $(this).css("background", "red");
    } else {
      $(this).css("background", "blue");
    }
  });
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
$('#t').on('click', function() {
  var sum = 0;
  $('div.myDiv').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('span:empty').length > 0) {
      $(this).css("background", "red");
    } else {
      $(this).css("background", "blue");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div.myDiv {
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="myDiv">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="myDiv">
          <span>b-1</span>
          <span>b-2</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row"></div>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <input type="button" value="ss" id="t">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Updated fiddle with required libraries and an explicit height set (or the "red" div would be invisible): https://jsfiddle.net/wecLLgmc/1/

Comment: @GregPettit I updated the answer, to take your tips into account.